# How to specify a scenario wildcard in Zabbix expression

Tags: zabbix, regular-expressions

I'm using Zabbix 2.0 am wondering how to use a wildcard or regular expression for a scenario name of a trigger?

For example, I have the following trigger:

```
MyHost:web.test.fail[<scenario>].avg(#5)}>0.4
```

I would like to replace `<scenario` with a wildcard or regular expression.

Comment: As far as i remember you can only use regexp for function , not for the key.